# Microsoft Graph paging with list message and list reply?

Tags: pagination, microsoft-graph-api, message, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm integrating Microsoft Teams into my app using microsoft graph API.
But with the API to get list message, I used parameter $top={pageSize} for pagination, then I got surprised that in the first call, the response returned "pageSize - 1" records, not exactly the number of pageSize.

In contrary, the API to get list replies, it returned exactly "pageSize" records in the first call.

I don't understand why is there a difference like this between message and relpy. Can anyone help me?

This is the pattern of the API that I used:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{teamId}/channels/{channelId}/messages?$top={pageSize}](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/%7BteamId%7D/channels/%7BchannelId%7D/messages?$top=%7BpageSize%7D)

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{teamId}/channels/{channelId}/messages/{messageId}/replies?$top={pageSize}](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/%7BteamId%7D/channels/%7BchannelId%7D/messages/%7BmessageId%7D/replies?$top=%7BpageSize%7D)

Answer (score 0):

We could able to reproduce the issue on our side raised a bug.